# Как здес правильно исползовать language?

Tags: php

Я новичок здесь и не знаю, почему это показывает, так ☺

***Устарело: создание динамического свойства Language::$languages устарело в C:\xampp\htdocs\test\class.Language.php в строке 8***

```
  function detectLanguage()
{
    global $DEFAULT_LANGUAGE;
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) {
        $this->languages = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']; /*Здесь ошибка*/
        $this->language = substr($this->languages, 0, 2);   /* И Здесь ошибка*/
        return $this->language;
    } else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) {
        $this->user_agent = explode(";", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($this->user_agent); $i++) {
            $this->languages = explode("-", $this->user_agent[$i]);
            if (sizeof($this->languages) == 2) {
                if (strlen(trim($this->languages[0])) == 2) {
                    $size = sizeof($this->language);
                    $this->language[$size] = trim($this->languages[0]);
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->language[0];
    } else {
        $this->language = $DEFAULT_LANGUAGE;
        return $this->language;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Теперь нельзя просто так свойства класса создавать заполнением. Объявите свойство в классе, тогда ошибки не будет:

```
class Language
{
    private array $languages; // Вот это требуется от Вас

    ...
    
    function detectLanguage()
    {
        global $DEFAULT_LANGUAGE;
        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) {
            $this->languages = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
            $this->language = substr($this->languages, 0, 2);
            return $this->language;
        } else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) {
            $this->user_agent = explode(";", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    
            for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($this->user_agent); $i++) {
                $this->languages = explode("-", $this->user_agent[$i]);
                if (sizeof($this->languages) == 2) {
                    if (strlen(trim($this->languages[0])) == 2) {
                        $size = sizeof($this->language);
                        $this->language[$size] = trim($this->languages[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
            return $this->language[0];
        } else {
            $this->language = $DEFAULT_LANGUAGE;
            return $this->language;
        }
    }   
}
```